# Making php script executable

Tags: php

I'm filling out a job application which has asked me to write a function which you submit to them as a .php file. The last line of the specification says:

> Make sure your file can be executed from the command line: php meats.php (this helps us to check if the code works before even looking at it)

Does anyone know what that means? I've checked that function works fine on my hosting environment but I'm just not sure there is something else I need to do??

Thank you

Comment: It means that you should be able to execute the script from the command line.Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Are you sure that you really want to apply for a php job if you cannot answer that yourself? Answer: YES YOU DO! But before, learn what that means: php _can_ be used inside an http server, but like any other programming language its usage is only limited by your imagination. For example you can simply start a script on the command line: `php /path/to/script.php`

Comment: if you can point me in the right direction I'm happy to teach myself. I have taught myself everything and this stuff hasn't come up yet. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think I did just that. What is unclear? What a command line is? How to start php on the command line? The path to your script?

Comment: yes I didn't get your reply till i posted, thank you

Comment: http://www.jarrodoberto.com/articles/2011/12/running-php-from-the-command-line-basics

Comment: Hm, you didn't "get my reply", but you answer to it? OK, lol

Comment: I believe you edited it, and added to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, you'll need to make sure it's not using anything that's dependent on being <strike><strike>run</strike> *rendered* in the browser</strike> *executed on the server via a client browser's HTTP request to a webserver, which may send data back to the browser for rendering*. These include `$_GET`,`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (for relative web paths), and other such variables. You may need to convert these to use [magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) or otherwise work around your limitations.

I'm about to send you down a rabbit hole if you've never been to your command line, but you should SSH into your web server and try to execute your php file just like they said. You'll navigate to the directory with the file and run

```
php meats.php
```

Then, the command line will spit out any `echo`s that you've got, or do whatever else your code does.

Comment: A php script is _never_ "run in the bowser".

Comment: Updated just to be totally clear, but c'mon.

Comment: A php script is also not _rendered_ in a browser, not even in italic, except of you enclose the php code in html `<pre>` tags maybe...

Comment: Thank you for that some good advice, I'm getting could not open input file meat.php when I cd to the directory and try: php meat.php am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is it `meat.php` or `meats.php`? That error means the PHP interpreter (the thing that actually "runs" the script) doesn't see `meat.php` as a valid script to execute.

Comment: Oh my, yes I was running meat.php even though the script is meats.php. Thank you for the help!!! It runs just fine :)

Comment: Awesome! Good luck on the job hunt.